# Log4j logging in catalina-date.log

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

I have a servlet and I want to log in the file: **catalina-< date >.log**. The configuration file **log4j.properties** (located in catalina.home/lib) is the same as in the http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html (log4j paragraph):

```
log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append=true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding=UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
```

The problem is that it doesnt log in the **catalina-< date >.log** but in the **catalina**. It appears that the appender is not configured properly. The file **catalina** appears to be created from **log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.** in the configuration.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Where is your log4j.properties file? The file catalina.out comes from Tomcat's startup scripts and is the recipient of messages printed to standard output -- it's got nothing to do with log4j.

Comment: This is not true. I have also a configuration for the stdout, which prints the messages in the console, but not in the file of logging.

Comment: Tomcat's startup scripts redirect stdout to CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out. If you specify the same path for a log4j appender's file, one will clobber the other. I highly recommend against your strategy shown above.

Comment: Ok, but do you have any solution for that? I want to add appenders to my loggers in the application, and everything that is logged from them, to log in the catalina.out (catalina-<date>.log).

Comment: What is your deployment environment? Win32 or *NIX? Also, how to you launch Tomcat? (The solution may depend on how you do things).

Comment: Win32, tomcat is lunched from the command line.

Comment: Can you make this change from: log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.
to log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.log and see if it made any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rotate logs/catalina.out on win32 when using the startup scripts to launch Tomcat, one option is to install a log-ratating logger such as chronolog (which might be a *NIX-only thing) and then modify catalina.out to *pipe* standard output to that process instead of redirecting to a file.

**Update**: A better option (in general on win32) is probably to use Tomcat's service installer and run Tomcat as a service, but I don't believe it makes things any easier to rotate your log file.

The best option of course is not to write to standard out in the first place to avoid ever needing to rotate this log file.

Comment: Well, I think its not the problem of using another logger. The problem is that the configuration file doesnt work properly and I dont know why. It creates a new "catalina" file instead of creating a new "catalina-<date>.log" file

Comment: What configuration file are you talking about? Tomcat does not use any logging configuration whatsoever to create the logs/catalina.out file: it uses output redirection from within the bin/catalina.bat file: it always logs to logs/catalina.out unless you do in and change the script. There simply is no configuration.

Comment: Well, I am not an expert on how Tomcat does it but I think it redirects it to the configuration that you put in the **catalina.home/lib**. It looks like this part of the configuration of the logging is not considered. **log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'** . it doesnt create a **catalina-date.log** but just a file called **catalina**. The question is so obvious.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't ship with any logging configuration in CATALINA_HOME/lib. If you put something there it's probably not being read unless there is additional configuration. At any rate, I promise you that logs/catalina.out is controlled solely by the script that launches Tomcat. Feel free to read the script to confirm this for yourself.

Comment: Well, this doesnt change the topic of my Question. Its from the [http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) that you can check that you can change the appenders, that its not related where does the tomcat implement the logging. I can configure it and the problem is the **date** that its not configurable

Comment: Read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Console.  I'm sorry that you don't like it, but this is the answer to your question.

Comment: But my question is not how to Log smth in Tomcat, instead is how to configure tomcat log4j to log in the tomcat file. Tomcat logs it in the wrong file and appears like the configuration is not correct. I ask for something totally different on what you answer

Comment: If you want log4j to log to catalina.out, then use ConsoleAppender (which is totally stupid: you shouldn't be logging to stdout at all). If you want to change the name of catalina.out, you'll have to modify the startup script. I can't sat it any more plainly than that.

Comment: pokeRex110 I have the same problem. I followed the instructions to switch logging to log4J and all the files that it creates are lacking the .date.log extensions, so, for example, I'm getting catalina instead of catalina.date.log. Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Comment: `catalina.out` is created by redirecting standard output from the startup scripts. If you use `jsvc` or run as a Windows Service, then you'll get different stdout/stderr streams (which you can configure). The problem is that log4j can't control the file used for standard output and standard error. Stop writing to those streams and you won't have to rotate those files.